# ap_log_error dumps on apache start with apache 2.4

Tags: c++, apache, aix, apache2.4

I have built a shared module on apache 2.4. I could get the apache build succesfull. On apache start there is a dump at the below line:

```
if (r != NULL)        ap_log_error(APLOG_MARK, APLOG_DEBUG, 0, r, "test");
```

I derefernce the structure variable r which is of type server_rec(apache struct) and below is the value in dbx

```
(dbx) p *r
(process = 0x000000011001fa88, next = (nil), error_fname = "logs/error_log", error_log = 0x000000011001fa10, log = (module_levels = (nil), level = 4), module_config = 0x0000000110053420, lookup_defaults = 0x0000000110054ef8, defn_name = (nil), defn_line_number = 0, is_virtual = '\0', port = 0, server_scheme = (nil), server_admin = "you@example.com", server_hostname = "isi081.wdf.sap.corp", addrs = 0x000000011004e410, timeout = 60000000, keep_alive_timeout = 5000000, keep_alive_max = 100, keep_alive = 1, names = (nil), wild_names = (nil), path = (nil), pathlen = 0, limit_req_line = 8190, limit_req_fieldsize = 8190, limit_req_fields = 100, context = (nil))
```

I do not see any corruption in memory. But still there is a dump on apache start.
If i comment out this line, then everything works as expected. Apache starts and i am able to complete the operation as well. But we would need this statement in order to have logging enabled. Is there any other alternative or fix for the same.

The same code is working for other platforms like linux,solaris and HP on apache 2.4.
ALso on aix with apache 2.2 the same code works. Only on apache 2.4 this issue is observed.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Below is the dump and r is of type server_rec:

Comment: Guess you should examine the core file with debugger. You might want to recompile Apache with '-g' option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you did not fully compile against 2.4 headers, and "ap_log_error" was not treated as the macro it is in 2.4.

Also, that server_rec named "r" is super misleading.  "r" is traditionally a request_rec.  I can't believe it's not actually the source of your problem, and maybe it is somehow indirectly.